# sh: can't access tty; job control turned off

Tags: gpio, boot, sd-card

Yesterday, I was programming GPIO controls for a robot in class and left for a few minutes to work with another group. I came back to find all the GPIO disconnected and `sh: can't access tty; job control turned off` on the screen.

So far, I have tried to reformat the SD card, used a different SD card, and typed `disablesafemode` into the `recovery.cmd` file. Nothing has worked so far.

Any suggestions?

Comment: How were you programming your GPIO pins? Python, shell, low level c? And what led to the can't access tty error? Running a script ?

Comment: It's useless to bump this question because good answers would need more input from @user39770 who was  "Last seen Jan 20 '16 at 18:19". Is there a way to tag questions as "probably unanswerable" or "needs input from question owner"?

Answer (score 0):

You may be damage you RPi. Did you tried SD cards at another RPi? I lived this problem before but in my case just GPIO pins wasn't working and i bought new RPi.

I suggest try your SD card on different RPi and if working you might be damaged. If not working re-download Noobs from https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/ and try at working RPi before and after try your corrupted one.

SFMBE